# Distributional and weak solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Consider a differential equation,

$$L(T)=f,$$

where $L$ is a linear ordinary differential operator with smooth coefficients and $f$ is a $L_{loc}^1$ function.

Does there always exist a distribution T such that above equation holds (if not what conditions on $f$ are sufficient to guarantee that)?

What is an example s.t. distribution solution exists but any function is not a solution in the sense of distribution? I know examples of ODE's for which there are distributional solutions that are not functions (e.g. $x^2y’=0$), but I want an example in which no function is a solution but distributional solution exist.

I am learning this stuff on my own so questions might be trivial. Thanks for any help!

Comment: There are at least examples where only the trivial solution exists as a function, but non-trivial solutions exist as distributions: $xu(x)=0$ has only the trivial solution in $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ but $u(x)=C\delta(x)$ as distributions.

Comment: @md2perpe Thanks.